# git-tfs: How do I clone a tfs project that contains spaces

Tags: git, tfs, clone, git-tfs

I am trying to clone a TFS repository using git-tfs.

It works great with TFS projects that don´t have a space in the name, such as:

```
git tfs clone http://tfs:8080/ $/TeamProject/folder
```

But I also have some projects/folders that has both spaces and swedish characters in it:

```
git tfs clone http://tfs:8080/ $/TeamProject/my swedish åäö folder1/folder2
```

When I run the command I get:

```
The item $/TeamProject/my swedish åäö folder1/folder2 does not exist at the spcified version.
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Try enclosing the whole path in double quotes.

Comment: That worked partly. I can now clone projects/folders with space, but still having issues with swedish characters

Comment: You could try urlencoding them? I'm not sure how it handles such characters.

Comment: Im not even able to write swedish characters in the git bash console. Is it possible to change language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by renaming the projects in TFS, and removed the swedish characters.

As Polynomial said, it is possible to have folders/projects that contains space if you enclose the path with double quotes.

Comment: yes double quote should save you for space characters but the last version of git-tfs should now resolve your problem of swedish characters...

Answer (score 19):

Here's a working example of cloning a TFS (TFVC) repository using `git tfs` where the TFS (TFVC) repository contains spaces:

`git tfs clone http://tfs:8080/ $/"Team Project/Folder Name"`

The key "trick" to making it work is to put the double quotes around the team project / folder name (but don't put them around the `$/` part).

i.e. `$/"Team Project/Folder Name"`

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. Can you remember (and add) the context?

Comment: How does it not make sense? The original question was "How do I clone a tfs project that contains spaces" and I've provided an example of how to clone a tfs project that contains spaces e.g. `$/"Team Project/Folder Name"`.

Comment: Your answer doesn't mention what's wrong, or even whether there is a way to fix it. (It is, in effect "Something about quotes.") This may seem nitpicky, but establishing *credibility* is just as important as having the right code there.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me.